# how important is clearing the buffer indexes in netty

Tags: netty

I was wondering in terms of performance how important is to call netty `ByteBuffer#clear()` in ChannelRead after buffer is set to the context.

As far as I check in the java doc `clear()` only clears the two pointers writerIndex and readerIndex.

Example code:

```
@Override
public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) {
    ByteBuf in = (ByteBuf) msg;

    String payload = in.toString(CharsetUtil.UTF_8).replaceAll("\\s", "");
    System.out.println("Server received (" + payload.length() + "): " + payload);

    String json = "{\"userId\": \"" + payload + "\"}";

    if (!payload.isEmpty()) {
        ctx.write(Unpooled.copiedBuffer(json, CharsetUtil.UTF_8));
    }

    in.clear();
}
```

Comment: what you mean with "set to the context" ?

Comment: Hey @NormanMaurer I just updated with code example so you can get better understanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to call `in.clear()`. What you need to do is call `in.release()`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Still I can't understand what are the cases to calling clear(). Can you tell me why I need to call release over clear?

Comment: ByteBuf is reference counted so you need to call release() to release the underlying memory. You may want to call clear() when you want to reset the reader / writer index to 0.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I was about to make profiler to check the results but didn’t find the time to do it yet